# My Java regex doesn't work properly

Tags: java, regex

I wrote a regex expression as below, which used extract the dates from string:

```
(Monday|Tuesday|Wednesday|Thursday|Friday|Saturday|Sunday)(\*){0,2}\s+\d{1,2}\s+(January|February|March|April|May|June|July|August|September|October|November|December)\s+\d{4}
```

Before convert to java regex expression I tested here http://regexr.com?35vlm

the results looks no problem, it matches what I want.

**"el" object is an string type arraylist**:

```
holiday: New Year's Day Wednesday 1 January 2014
holiday: Chinese New Year Friday 31 January 2014 Saturday 1 February 2014
holiday: Good Friday Friday 18 April 2014
holiday: Labour Day Thursday 1 May 2014
holiday: Vesak Day Tuesday 13 May 2014
holiday: Hari Raya Puasa Monday 28 July 2014
holiday: National Day  Saturday 9 August 2014
holiday: Hari Raya Haji  Sunday* 5 October 2014
holiday: Deepavali  Thursday** 23 October 2014
holiday: Christmas Day Thursday 25 December 2014
```

**Question** is in java some dates are missed, some are matched, I also tested here http://java-regex-tester.appspot.com/, same error.

**Update:**

Full version of my code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;


public class Tester {

    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws IOException 
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        updateSingaporeHolidayCalendar();
    }
    
public static void updateSingaporeHolidayCalendar() throws IOException{
        
        String url = "http://www.mom.gov.sg/employment-practices/leave-and-holidays/Pages/public-holidays-2014.aspx";
        Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();

        Elements holidays = document.select("#contentarea table tr");
        // System.out.println("12312312");
        //System.out.println("web page context: " + question);
        List<String> el = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(int i = 2; i < holidays.size() + 1; i++){
            if((i&1) == 1) continue;
            Elements threeGroup = holidays.get(i-2).getElementsByTag("td");
            
            int j = 2;
            for(Element e : threeGroup){
                if(j-- != 0) continue;
                j = 2;
                el.add(e.text());
            }
        }
        
        
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(Monday|Tuesday|Wednesday|Thursday|Friday|Saturday|Sunday)(\\*){0,2}\\s+\\d{1,2}\\s+(January|February|March|April|May|June|July|August|September|October|November|December)\\s+\\d{4}");
      
        //out put
        for(int k = 0; k < el.size(); k++){
            
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(el.get(k));
            // Check all occurrences
            while (matcher.find()) {
                //System.out.print("Start index: " + matcher.start());
                //System.out.print(" End index: " + matcher.end());
                System.out.println(" Found: " + matcher.group());
            }
            System.out.println("holiday: " + el.get(k));
        }

    }

}
```

external Jar : JSoup.jar

**Output:**

```
  Found: Wednesday 1 January 2014
holiday: New Year's Day Wednesday 1 January 2014
 Found: Saturday 1 February 2014
holiday: Chinese New Year Friday 31 January 2014 Saturday 1 February 2014
holiday: Good Friday Friday 18 April 2014
 Found: Thursday 1 May 2014
holiday: Labour Day Thursday 1 May 2014
holiday: Vesak Day Tuesday 13 May 2014
holiday: Hari Raya Puasa Monday 28 July 2014
holiday: National Day  Saturday 9 August 2014
 Found: Sunday* 5 October 2014
holiday: Hari Raya Haji  Sunday* 5 October 2014
holiday: Deepavali  Thursday** 23 October 2014
 Found: Thursday 25 December 2014
holiday: Christmas Day Thursday 25 December 2014
holiday:  
holiday:
```

**Solved**:

as @Pshemo said, "Data you got from site contain also no-break space which can be written in HTML as   and apparently it doesn't belong to \s class. To solve this problem replace each \s with [\s\u00A0] to include this character (written with Unicode identifier)."

So change the expression to :

```
 Pattern pattern = Pattern
        .compile("(Monday|Tuesday|Wednesday|Thursday|Friday|Saturday|Sunday)(\\*){0,2}[\\s\u00A0]+\\d{1,2}[\\s\u00A0]+(January|February|March|April|May|June|July|August|September|October|November|December)[\\s\u00A0]+\\d{4}");
```

solved the issue.

Comment: Sorry but could you say something more about problem you are facing? [It seems to be working fine](http://ideone.com/kbcwgH) for me... without last two lines but since you used size-2 I assume that is correct.

Comment: It looks fine on http://java-regex-tester.appspot.com/ too.

Comment: What is the output that your program prints to the console?

Comment: @JasonC did you tried my least code? does it work?

Comment: No, I don't have JSoup.

Comment: @JasonC please see the update of output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data you got from site contain also `no-break space` which can be written in HTML as `&#160;` and apparently it doesn't belong to `\\s` class. To solve this problem replace each `\\s` with `[\\s\u00A0]` to include this character (written with Unicode identifier).

So your regex can look like

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern
        .compile("(Monday|Tuesday|Wednesday|Thursday|Friday|Saturday|Sunday)(\\*){0,2}[\\s\u00A0]+\\d{1,2}[\\s\u00A0]+(January|February|March|April|May|June|July|August|September|October|November|December)[\\s\u00A0]+\\d{4}");
```

Comment: +1 Very interesting that with regex non-breaking **space** is not a "space"

Comment: @Bohemian yes it is interesting, but it makes sense since it is not used to separate words like new line marks, tabulators, but space that makes two words one so it is kind of "letter/character", not space :)

Answer (score 0):

Well I can say for sure you'll miss the last two, because your iteration stops 2 elements short, ie change:

```
k < el.size() - 2
```

To

```
k < el.size()
```

or better yet, use a foreach:

```
for (String s : el) {
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(a);
    // ...
}
```

Your regex looks OK.

Comment: the reason I removed the last 2 is I don't need them, I don't think it's the problem, I tested in java "holiday: Good Friday Friday 18 April 2014", "holiday: Vesak Day Tuesday 13 May 2014", "holiday: Hari Raya Puasa Monday 28 July 2014", "holiday: National Day  Saturday 9 August 2014", "holiday: Deepavali  Thursday** 23 October 2014" are missed. others are matched.

Comment: @user1837485 I just tested your code and it seems to be working fine. Take a look here http://ideone.com/kbcwgH.

Comment: @Pshemo your code works, one moment,I'll pasted all the full code, actually I fetched the string list from a website.

Comment: @Pshemo is there any way to import external lib into IDEONE?

Comment: @Pshemo I pasted my code there, but JSoup.jar is missing, http://ideone.com/Ew9i94

Comment: @user1837485 I am afraid you cant do that. Also to get solution to your problem check [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18266056/1393766).

Answer (score 0):

your for loop `for(int k = 0; k < el.size() - 2; k++)` was limited to `el.size() - 2`
try removing the -2 to loop through all the elements in your list